# How to mocking user input in unit test in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I'm running some problems when writing my unit test code using mochaJS. Here is my code:

```
//index.js
var query = require('cli-interact');// helper tools for interacting synchronously with user at command line. 

module.exports = function main() {
    while (true){
    let choice = query.getNumber("plz choice from（1～3）：");//waiting for user's input;
    }
    if(choice === 3){
      console.log("you entered 3");
    }
//...other code
}

//test_spec.js
var chai = require("chai");
var sinon = require("sinon");
var sinonChai = require("sinon-chai");
var expect = chai.expect;
chai.use(sinonChai);
var main = require("../index.js");
describe("test input ", function(){
    sinon.spy(console, 'log');

    it("enter 3", function(){
        main();
        //now the test code block here, I want to automatically input 3,but don't know how.
        let result = console.log.calledWith("you entered 3")
        expect(result).to.equal(true);
    });

});
```

As the code shows above, when I run the test case, the terminal shows a line "plz choice from（1～3）：" and waiting for my input, once I type 3 and enter, the test case will pass.

Now I want to automate the process, what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I don't understand the need of 'query.getNumber' inside infinite while loop.

```
let choice = query.getNumber("plz choice from（1～3）：");//waiting for user's
```

If this is removed, you can use some robo node modules to achieve this. 
Check robotjs https://www.npmjs.com/package/robotjs

index.js

```
 var query = require('cli-interact');
    let main = () => {
        let choice;
        while (choice != 3) {
            choice = query.getNumber("plz choice from（1～3）："); 
            console.log('your choice is : ' + choice);
            if (choice === 3) {
                console.log("you entered 3");
            }
        }
    };
    module.exports = main;
```

test_spec.js

```
var chai = require("chai");
var sinon = require("sinon");
var sinonChai = require("sinon-chai");
var expect = chai.expect;
chai.use(sinonChai);
var main = require("../index.js");
var robot = require("robotjs");

var roboInput = (input) => {
    robot.typeString(input);
    robot.keyTap("enter");
};
var roboInputArr = (inputs) => {
    inputs.forEach(ip =>{
        roboInput(ip);
    });
};
describe("test input ", function() {
    sinon.spy(console, 'log');
    it("enter 3", function() {
        roboInputArr([1,2,3]);
        main();
        let result = console.log.calledWith("you entered 3")
        expect(result).to.equal(true);
    });
});
```

> ```
> test input
> ----------- 
> enter 3: 
> plz choice from(1~3):1 
> your choice is : 1 
> plz choice from(1~3):2 
> your choice is : 2 
> plz choice from(1~3):3 
> your choice is : 3 
> you entered 3 
> Pass
> ```

Comment: query.getNumber() is a api from module 'cli-interact',which can be found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cli-interact),It accept user's input synchronously.

Comment: Why do you want that inside a infinite loop ( while (true)) ?  It wont exit the loop and keeps asking for user input

Comment: The truth is, that there are couple more options, one of which asks user to add student's grades to the database, I assume there will be more than one student, after user input a student's grades, it will go back to the main function and ask if user want to add more grades or exit the program(choose 3).

Comment: one more question. Intuitively, in the test case,we should run main and then mock the input like below: 
      main();
      roboInputArr([1,2,3]);
but why your's is 
      roboInputArr([1,2,3]);
      main();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152687/discussion-between-ponmudi-vn-and-yu-duan).